# Wrong layout when converting from csv to excel

Tags: python, excel, csv, excel-2010, openpyxl

I have the following code however the output does not appear correctly.
Any idea as to why it is causing this.  I do not have this issue in Linux

I have tried to add: encoding="utf-8"

However this did not resolve the issue.

```
import csv
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

f = open('C:\HAHA.csv')
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=':')
for row in reader:
    ws.append(row)
f.close()

wb.save('C:\HAHA.xlsx')
```

[image]

Comment: what's wrong with the layout ? the alignment inside the cells  for numbers ?

Comment: @PRMoureu As you can see in image to left, its all getting stuck in one column rather than like on the right with 3 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're telling the `csv` module to use `:` as a delimiter whereas your actual file uses the (standard) comma to delimit records.

```
f = open('C:\HAHA.csv') 
reader = csv.reader(f)
```

Also, depending on your Python version, you should use the newline parameter or rb mode when opening the file. Read the docs for the [`csv` module (Python 2)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) or the [`csv` module (Python 3)](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your delimiter is `,` not `:`:

```
import csv
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

with open('C:\HAHA.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        ws.append(row)

wb.save('C:/HAHA.xlsx')
```